# Bootstrap dropdown('toggle') method doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to toggle a bootstrap dropdown with dropdown('toggle') method but it does not toggle the drop down (open on first click but doesn't close when clicked again). I want to do it only through dropdown('toggle') method. I am using the following code:

JavaScript-

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(){
        $(this).dropdown('toggle');
    });
});
```

HTML-

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something here</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

It would be great if you tell me about any example on, how to enable multiple drop down in a navbar manually using JavaScript.

fiddle of code at: http://jsfiddle.net/alaxmenon/HNL3c/

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to use the data attributes you just need to do this:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
  $(this).next(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
});
```

`dropdown('toggle')` won't work unless you use data attributes.

Bootply: **http://www.bootply.com/67728**

Comment: Works like a charm! Had been struggling with this for almost an hour! Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(e){
        $(this).dropdown('toggle');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd remove `data-toggle="dropdown"` from `<a>` (if it still there)

```
$(function() {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked in my case. The Pluralsight course "Building Web Applications with ASP.NET Core MVC" had a bug in the "Adding View Components" video in section 7 where the dropdown doesn't work. Adding this to the _Layout.cshtml (or somewhere equivalent) got it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Replace href="#" with href="javascript:void(0);"

Comment: doesn't work. I want to toggle the dropdown on click of main drop down link (<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>).

Comment: Have you write code like this <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

Comment: Create fiddle for the same so that I can do it for you.

Comment: try this <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

Comment: you can check fiddle at (http://jsfiddle.net/alaxmenon/HNL3c/), i don't want to use data attributes, only want to do it through dropdown('toggle') method.

Comment: There is something wrong but you can do this alternatively like this - http://jsfiddle.net/HNL3c/4/

Answer (score -1):

Use bootstrap-dropdown.js , you dont need to write any extra js for toggling the dropdown.

Comment: I don't want to use data attribute. I want to do it manually through dropdown('toggle') method.